# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named <name-of-module>

Tags: python

This is my project structure:

```
maths/
     __init__.py
     trig.py
     coord.py
     pitch.py
models/
     __init__.py
     model.py
```

In `model.py`, I have:

```
import sys 
sys.path.append("../")

from maths.pitch import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
   # my routines
```

In `pitch.py`, I have:

```
from trig import calculate_distance_angles
```

---

When I run `model.py`, I'm getting the error:

```
  File "model.py", line 38, in <module>
    from maths.pitch import *
  File "../maths/pitch.py", line 9, in <module>
    from trig import calculate_distance_angles
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trig'
```

---

How do I fix this?

Comment: have you tried `from .trig import ...`?

Answer (score 4):

The error came from here: `from trig import calculate_distance_angles`. I suppose you are looking for your `maths/trig.py` file:

```
maths/
     __init__.py
     trig.py  <-- this one
     coord.py
     pitch.py
models/
     __init__.py
     model.py
```

On your `sys.path`, you may have this:

- (all the original `sys.path` stuff)...
- `"../"` (added at `model.py`)

But the `maths` model, as far as we can see, is not on `sys.path`. If that's true, you may have to modify the import as follows. This should work:

```py
from maths.trig import calculate_distance_angles
```